# DNS server Windows Server 2008 fail resolving

Tags: windows-server-2008, dns-server, domain-name-system

I have a machine running Windows Server 2008 (not r2) and I have installed Active Directory and DNS server.

On my client machine, in the network properties, I have set Obtain an Ip Address Automatically and Use the following DNS server addresses:
192.168.0.99 (which is the IP address of my Windows Server 2008)

Everything works fine. I have internet access and it uses my Windows Server 2008 as the DNS server. However, after a few times surfing the web,  I get the server "xxxxx" can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. So I disable my network interface and re enable it and everything works fine for another bunch of minutes. And so on and so on.

There is clearly something wrong with my DNS server but I can't see what because it works fine for some period of time or number of requests and after some times it fails.

What could be the cause ?

In my network interface for my Windows Server I have set 
Use the following Ip Address:

IP address : 192.168.0.99

Subnet mask : 255.255.255.0

Default gateway : 192.168.0.1 (my router IP address)

And I have set :

Use the following DNS server addresses :
192.168.0.1
none

It happens on every client machine I connect to my server. All of them, when I set up 
Use the following DNS server addresses:
192.168.0.99

after few minutes it fails !

Answer (score 1):

1. Your dhcp server should be handing out the DNS servers (and suffix) to the DHCP clients, not statically setting it like you are.
2. Your AD/DNS server should point to itself (127.0.0.1) for DNS if there's only this single server and you should have forwarders setup in DNS to forward non-authoritative queries to an EXTERNAL DNS server, not your local router/gateway.